# Regex to remove an appended URL from an actual URL

Tags: c#, string

I'm looking for a regular expression pattern that can remove a URL that is appended to the end of an actual URL.

For example, given the string `https://test1-sc10-auth.comhttps://test1-sc10.com/search-results#e=0&q=news`, I want to remove the appended URL `https://test1-sc10.com` so that the result is `https://test1-sc10-auth.com/search-results#e=0&q=news`.

I have tried using various regex patterns, but the closest result I got was `https://test1-sc10.com/search-results#e=0&q=news` using the pattern `^(.*?)((?:https?://\S+))(?:.*?\2)+?(.*)$`.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need a regex if you could do it handling the string?

Comment: and why do you have a duplicate in your url? That URL is not valid.

Comment: Regex isn't really the tool for correcting malformed URLs, let alone _parse_ URLs.

Comment: @gunr2171 then how to correct this?

Comment: @LeandroBardelli off course I know its not valid and I want to correct the url

Comment: have you considered figuring out what is corrupting the url in the first place? Maybe you're trying to solve the wrong problem

Comment: This is possibly an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find what is happening, and also regex is an overkill to do this as we explain in the comments, try with this code:

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/l7szjf

```
    string badurl = "https://test1-sc10-auth.comhttps://test1-sc10.com/search-results#e=0&q=news"; //your original url
    int position = badurl.IndexOf("http",6); //get the position of any http or https after the first one, assuming you only have only 2 times repeated the code.
    string goodurl = badurl.Substring(position); //get everything after that position
    Console.WriteLine(goodurl); //test it
```

You can solve it in one line:

```
url = url.Substring(url.IndexOf("http",6));
```